# How to fill above ground pool ditch

Tags: patio, gravel

the seller of the house I purchased removed the above ground pool, there is a 17 by 26 feet opening that is about 6 inches deep. 221 ft3.  There is a thin layer of packed down sand which has smaller rocks around the edge.  I'm interested in filling and converting the hole to a patio.

What material would I need to fill the whole as a solid base.

Comment: What type of patio would you be putting over top - concrete, stone, etc? It's very likely that you will need some sort of base / drainage for the patio, which would fit (at least partially) in the existing hole.

Comment: Hi @mmathis.  I would probably use large square pavers in the center to make a square.  The shape of the ditch is an elongated hexagon (pool shape).  So I would fill the whole with the. See, then create the patio starting in the center with a square/rectangle shape around the center.

Answer (score 1):

3/4 minus crushed quary makes a great base for just about any type of patio. I use a plate compactor and have finished with pavers and poured concrete in the past with excellent results. I would caution not to use crushed river rock as it will not lock together as well and tends to move around compared to crushed quarry rock.

Comment: Is it a diyer, type job, I can follow instructions and have done so all around my house.  One question I have is do I need to remove the existing sand first?

Comment: It depends on how deep the sand is if only an inch or so the rock will settle in the sand. If it is deeper sand I would pull most of it to the side put my rock down then put the sand on the rock and pack it wet this will make an awesome base.